How to create a multi-select document property for Word 2016?
How can I create a Custom document property that allows multiple value selection for Word 2016?
Ex. I have one document that is applicable to Doctors, Nurses, Managers.
The author should be able to select each applicable role from the list of all roles.

Welcome to Superuser. Can you share with us the research you have done and what you have tried so far attempting to solve this yourself? Please add that info to the question itself, and do not add new info down here in comments. Also, can you explain a little further how having documents applicable to multiple types of staff is relevant to the question you're asking. It does feel as though you found a problem, and have made some assumptions regarding how to solve that. Perhaps taking a few steps back, to before the assumptions, will help us present a solution that is already compatible.

I have used Microsoft's Help feature, and did some general searches. It appears there is a limitation on what I can choose for the property (Text, Date, Yes / No, etc.). I know when the organization had SharePoint, this was not a problem.
